# como hacer un if que cuando me tire un error en sql me tire un error

Tags: php, sql, api

como dice el titulo quería tratar de que cada vez que me tire un error SQL ya sea por algún motivo, me tire un error en mi response de API.

Ejemplo yo quiero hacer un insert y cuando mi Genero_ID que es la clave foranea ponen una que no corresponde, salte un mensaje, por que si no me tira un error de SQL y no queda agradable a la vista... alguno sabe como puedo hacerlo? De la forma que yo lo tengo no me tira el error...

```php
public function insertApiGame($params = null) {
    $game = $this->getData();
    if (empty($game->Nombre) || empty($game->Fecha) || empty($game->Precio) || empty($game->Descripcion) || empty($game->Genero_ID)) {
        $this->view->response("Complete los datos", 400);
    } else {
        $id = $this->model->InsertGame($game->Nombre, $game->Fecha, $game->Precio, $game->Descripcion, $game->Genero_ID);
        $game = $this->model->getGame($id);
        if ($game) { 
            $this->view->response($game, 201);
        } else if (!$game) {
            $this->view->response("nonon",500);
        }
    }
}
```

No se si mis IF estan mal puestos o que pero yo creo que si pero no me funciona me sigue tirando erro de SQL en cada post que hago a proposito MAL para ver si me funciona el codigo...

Espero respuesta mucha gracias!!!

Comment: Has intentado poner el codigo dentro de un bloque try/catch?

Comment: lo pensé y lo hice pero no me funciono, me dirías la sintaxis? Gracias por la respuesta!!

Comment: `try { $game = .... y todo lo que tienes dentro de tu funcion } catch (e) { //aqui escribes como quieres manejar el error}`

Comment: A menos que el método `InsertGame` arroje excepciones, deberías verificar la condición de error en la conexión o la sentencia si es el caso.